# Split columns at delimiter, fill new cols with values from split

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I split a column at a delimiter and fill those new columns with values corresponding to the contents of each row?

I have a column `functionality` that originally contained some combination of up to five sentences. I used `mutate()` to replace these sentences with keywords using the following:

```
mutate(functionality = str_replace(functionality, 
"A long sentence about audits.", 
"audits")) %>% mutate(functionality = str_replace(functionality, 
"A long sentence about patterns.", 
"patterns")) %>% mutate(functionality = str_replace(functionality, 
"A long sentence about monitoring.", 
"monitoring")) %>% mutate(functionality = str_replace(functionality, 
"A long sentence about reviews.", 
"reviews")) %>% mutate(functionality = str_replace(functionality, 
"A long sentence about investigations.", 
"investigations")) %>% as.data.frame()

<sup>Created on 2019-01-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>
```

Yielding the following column:

```
| functionality                                     |
|---------------------------------------------------|
| monitoring investigations patterns                |
| audits patterns                                   |
| reviews audits monitoring patterns                |
| reviews audits monitoring investigations patterns |
```

I would like to split `functionality` into separate columns `monitoring`, `investigations`, `patterns`, `audits`, and `reviews` and fill them with values corresponding to the original column, e.g.

```
| monitoring | investigations | patterns | review | audits |
|------------|----------------|----------|--------|--------|
| 1          | 1              | 1        | 0      | 0      |
| 0          | 0              | 1        | 0      | 1      |
| 1          | 0              | 1        | 1      | 1      |
| 1          | 1              | 1        | 1      | 1      |
```

I haven't had much success with `grepl` or `mutate_at`, but I'm relatively new to R so I may not be using the right code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do an `strsplit` on the 'functionality' column by space and then with `mtabulate` get the frequency

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(df1$functionality, " +"))
```

If the column `functionality` is `factor` class (based on wrapping of `as.data.frame` at the end - default gives `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`), then change it to `character` class before splitting

```
mtabulate(strsplit(as.character(df1$functionality), " +"))
#   audits investigations monitoring patterns reviews
#1      0              1          1        1       0
#2      1              0          0        1       0
#3      1              0          1        1       1
#4      1              1          1        1       1
```

---

Or as the OP was using `tidyverse`, we can get the expected output with `separate_rows/spread`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column('rn') %>% 
  separate_rows(functionality) %>%
  count(rn, functionality) %>%
  spread(functionality, n, fill = 0) %>% 
  select(-rn)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  audits investigations monitoring patterns reviews
#   <dbl>          <dbl>      <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
#1      0              1          1        1       0
#2      1              0          0        1       0
#3      1              0          1        1       1
#4      1              1          1        1       1
```

---

Or a `base R` option would be to convert the `list` of `vector`s into a two column data.frame with `stack` and get the `table`

```
table(stack(setNames(strsplit(as.character(df1$functionality), " +"), 
                  row.names(df1)))[2:1])
# values
#ind audits investigations monitoring patterns reviews
#  1      0              1          1        1       0
#  2      1              0          0        1       0
#  3      1              0          1        1       1
#  4      1              1          1        1       1
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(functionality = c("monitoring investigations patterns", 
"audits patterns", "reviews audits monitoring patterns", 
"reviews audits monitoring investigations patterns"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Comment: `separate_rows/spread` seems to have done the trick! This was a lot more intuitive than I thought. Thanks.